# What is the keyboard shortcut to focus 'Window' menu bar option

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Most apps have a menu bar option called 'Window'. I want to be able to open this menu option using a keyboard shortcut. I tried to create a shortcut using System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts but the shortcut does not do anything.

When opening the Window menu bar option, you can see a list of open windows. If there is a keyboard shortcut that can focus on this list, that is even better. I know I can cycle through opened windows using CMD + ~ so that is not what I want to do

Comment: I don't think there is one single command. Ctrl/F2 will focus to the Menu bar then W will go to the Window menu... though it may stall if there's another menu beginning with W. Then you need down arrow to pop the menu open & several more to reach the required line.

Comment: ctrl + F2 or ctrl + fn + F2 does not select the menu bar. I tested whilst chrome app is open. I am using Mac Book Pro Mid 2015 version

Comment: system prefs>keyboard>shortcuts?keyboard

Comment: Ok had to enable that shortcut from system prefs>keyboard>shortcuts?keyboard. Thanks @Tetsujin